# using usort with associative array inside symfony2 controller

Tags: php, sorting, symfony, usort

How can I use `usort` to sort an associative array inside a `symfony2` controller?

```
//sort
function compare($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['sort'], $b['sort']);
}

usort($content, 'compare');
```

That gives me the following error:

> Warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'compare' not found or invalid function name

as does putting it in its own private function like this

```
// sort
usort($content, '$this->compare');

return $content;

}

//sort
private function compare($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['sort'], $b['sort']);
}
```

this no change

```
// sort 
usort($content, 'compare');

return $content;

}

//sort
private function compare($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['sort'], $b['sort']);
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you just implement the function anonymously as the 2nd argument?

Comment: I read about that but not sure how to do it, a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try implementing the function anonymously:

```
usort($content, function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['sort'], $b['sort']);
});

return $content;
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. BTW is it never possible to declare a function inside a function (action) in symfony2, do you know?

Comment: It seems you can do something like in the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
usort($content, array($this, 'compare'));
```

This is how you pass an object method as a call-back. See [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#example-96) for examples.