# array_merge on 2 different entities collection, sort them by common property

Tags: php, sorting, symfony, merge, entity

I have 2 entities, Invoice and Advance. Each have a "paidAt" property.

In a controller, I fetch both Invoice and Advance within a date range. Then, I merge them into 1 single array and push it into my view, where I display them in a list.

Before pushing them to my view, I would like to sort them using the "paidAt" property. I found some multi-dimensional sorts functions on PHP doc, but all make use of php native function array_multisort()

So Symfony throws me an error : `Cannot use object of type Entity\Invoice as array`

Is there anyway to do what I'm looking for ?

Comment: please add some code first.

Comment: I think I have chosen a bad way to do that. Why don't you retrieve all the data as you need without merging and already sorted directly from database?

Comment: In my invoice repository, I can fetch both Invoice AND Advance entities ? isn't it a logic misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have getters `getPaidAt()` in both entities you can use for ascending order

```
usort(
    $collection,
    function($a, $b) {
        if ($a->getPaidAt() === $b->getPaidAt()) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($a->getPaidAt() < $b->getPaidAt())? -1 : 1;
    }
);
```

If you want to sort descending, just replace `<` by `>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `usort` just write your own compare function, it must be suitable for invoice and advance (do you have a superclass?)

http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php

additional Info: [using usort with associative array inside symfony2 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281306/using-usort-with-associative-array-inside-symfony2-controller)